# .htaccess non www subdomains to www with query string

Tags: .htaccess

Would like to redirect:

```
http://david.example.com/post/84747
```

To:

```
http://www.example.com/post/84747
```

keep in mind the subdomain and query parameter are dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} david.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:80$1 [L]
```